# Solr: search the same field with OR

Tags: solr, solrj

I am new to Solr and I want to find a solution to the following problem.
Suppose I have the following sequence:

> ABCDEFGHIJ{KLM}NOPWRSTU

In the searching process, the query can be any of the characters inside the  curly bracket { },
i.e., in this case the following queries should all return the above sequence.

> ABCD, JKNOP, JLNOP, JMNO, MNOP, HIJM

How can I implement such a search in Solr ?

One option I have found is to index all the combinations but that seems to be an impossible option in my case because these {} comes more often in my data.
Is there any way to perform such a search ?

Answer (score 0):

For partial matches: you index the terms with the [Ngram tokenizef](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Tokenizers). This will allow to match on parts of the term too.

For the regex part: it is not used too often, but Solr [supports regex](https://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/queryparser/org/apache/lucene/queryparser/classic/package-summary.html#Regexp_Searches) so you could run the query by creating a regex expression that matches what you want.

Comment: thanks for your reply.  Any Idea in indexing such an input string ?

Comment: added some more info